# What means (timeout) in "strace" -output? (mysql / php analyse)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, strace

I have a problem with a SQL query, which for reasons (which I do not understand), according to "strace" a (timeout) and will get up to run X-times?

> poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)

The PHP script which executes the query first looks in the database if the appropriate e-mail address is already in the database, if not it will be added it and if no error has occurred, an email is sent.

**Server:** Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

**DB:** mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

**Table:** InnoDB

**SQL:** (Example | Duration of 1 query: 0,031 sec.)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE user_email FROM mail_logging
WHERE mail_id_fk IN (142)
AND user_email = 'tester@foo.bar'
```

**SQL:** (EXPLAIN)

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
```

```
1   SIMPLE  mail_logging    ref id_mail,mail_id_fk,user_email   id_mail 775 const,const 1   Using where; Using index
```

**strace:** http://pastebin.com/FbYUZ1a3

**lsof:** http://pastebin.com/RyQcbWmj

edit: Thanks @VolkerK, now I see the problem :P

Comment: a) a unique index on the email field solves the problem without a possible race condition using a SELECT-if-nothing-found-INSERT combo. Just check for errno [1022  ER_DUP_KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key) b) Could you please add the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE user_email FROM mail_logging
WHERE mail_id_fk IN (142)
AND user_email = 'tester@foo.bar'` to your question text?

Comment: What @VolkerK said is the real solution to your problem. If you can avoid checking the integrity in PHP, you won't have a problem with the timeout at all.

Comment: According to the log `poll(..., ..., int timeout)` has been called with a timeout of 0, i.e. it is supposed to return immediately reporting the status and `timeout` (if I'm not mistaken) in this case just means "nothing to report". So, currently, I don't even see a `timeout problem` here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's signaling that the poll call has ended with a timeout. From the poll man page:

> The timeout argument specifies the minimum number of milliseconds that poll() will block. (This interval will be rounded up to the system clock granularity, and kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking interval may overrun by a small amount.) Specifying a negative value in timeout means an infinite timeout. Specifying a **timeout of zero causes poll() to return immediately, even if no file descriptors are ready**.